# Javascript Date check in and out control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using datepicker script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var datefield=document.createElement("input")
        datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
        if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
           document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
           document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
           document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n')
        }
</script>
<script>
    if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
            $('#data_inicial').datepicker();
            $('#data_final').datepicker();
        })
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<input id="data_inicial" type="date" value="" name="txtCheckIn"/>

<input id="data_final" type="date" name="txtCheckOut"/>
```

how to control check in and out dates,
not allow the user to enter a date of departure that the oldest entry?

Comment: Well, a first step would be to try comparing it, which I don't see any trace of in your code... Please note also that client-side validation is only for UX purposes; Any REAL validation can only be done server-side.

Comment: That's why I ask! I don't know how to do the validation! My code is correct, however I don't know how to validate dates

Comment: Well there are certainly a lot of resources on the Internet to help you start with it, was it for date validation or comparison (which one you need is still unclear to me). Basically, validation rules are quite easy and only the leap years are a bit tricky. With a set of simple `if` clauses you should get through it. Comparison is even simpler, even when your language doesn't include date comparison methods. Long story short : there's no problem not knowing how to do something, but you should first do the thinking and you will realize  how easy it is.

Answer (score 1):

In your input tags, there are `min` and `max` options you can set to contrain the date the user can enter. For example

`<input id="data_final" type="date" name="txtCheckOut" min="2014-07-01"/>`

See more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

Comment: Do any browsers, mobile or otherwise, actually pay attention to the "min" attribute?

Comment: ... and Chrome on Android still seems to have an off-by-one-day bug with both "min" and "max" attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use minDate option

```
$('[name=...]').datepicker("option", "minDate",startDate);
```